# How to iterate over long path names with any form of the Windows API

Tags: c, windows, winapi, ntfs

I have some files on a server that exceed the `MAX_PATH` limit.
I've repeatedly heard that you can list those files by pre-pending \\?\ to the path.  However, that doesn't solve the problem with `FindFirstFile[Ex]` and its partners as they use a data structure that limits file name length to `MAX_PATH`.

Is there any other way to iterate over the directory structure to find the files that have a name that is too long?  I've seen utilities that do it but none of them are available in source form.

Note that I have seen the blog entries from the .NET BCL folks and followed the links they provide.

I'd prefer to do this in C or C++ for simplicity but any freely available language will do for now.

Pointers to code, docs or anything useful are appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think there's a problem here. You are referring to the [`WIN32_FIND_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365740%28VS.85%29.aspx) which does indeed return filenames limited in length to `MAX_PATH`. But since this is only the filename part, and the path is omitted, there is no limitation.

Within a directory, an object (file or folder) is limited in length, typically to 255 characters. You can determine what this limit is with the `lpMaximumComponentLength` parameter of [`GetVolumeInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364993%28VS.85%29.aspx). I'd be surprised if any volume mounted in Windows could have a maximum component length in excess of 255.

The call to [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx) receives a null-terminates string, `lpFileName` which specifies the directory and filename (e.g. "*.txt", say) to search. The documentation states:

> In the ANSI version of this function,
>   the name is limited to MAX_PATH
>   characters. To extend this limit to
>   32,767 widecharacters, call the
>   Unicode version of the function and
>   prepend "\\?\" to the path.

Comment: Thanks David, you were absolutely correct.  This is what I get for not attempting to use the API before asking. :)  A really premature optimization?